# Which is more mechanically efficient, a bicycle or a unicycle?

Tags: efficient-energy-use

Human physiology aside, I wonder which device is more mechanically efficient, a bicycle or a unicycle?

Comment: http://www.glacierview.net/geowinters/balancePage.html see here u may get some of your answers

Comment: The simplest answer would come from ignoring the underlying physics of the whole  problem and look at how well humans are able to perform on both. You can guess that the bicycle is more efficient as a vehicle because humans are able to move faster and longer on one than a unicycle.

Comment: @A.C.A.C. It would seem to me that that analysis depends on the musculature of the human body. That's not what I'm interested in.

Answer (score 5):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_chain#Efficiency):

> A bicycle chain can be very energy efficient: one study reported efficiencies as high as 98.6%

Given that on a unicycle, there is no chain, it ought to heave fewer losses in the transmission system between foot and road.

However, if you look at overall efficiency of the whole human plus bicycle system for a specific activity, a conventional geared bicycle may be a more efficient means of transport due to gearing, the availability of brakes and other factors. Human pedalling efficiency is best when the person maintains an optimal pedalling cadence. This might be more difficult on a cycle that has no gears. At a minimum, the unicycle will have only one optimal speed where a geared cycle has many.

Answer (score 5):

A bicycle is mechanically more efficient as a vehicle.

In the unicycle we can't harness the kinetic energy of the vehicle.  The unicycle is direct drive, no gears, no "coasting".  The system (unicycle and rider) requires continual addition and removal of energy (kinetic energy) to remain balanced.  The center of rider mass must be over the contact point of the wheel to avoid the common asphalt body scrub. Continual acceleration and deceleration of the wheel keeps it beneath you.

The unicycle is mechanically less efficient due to the balance requirements.

I have ridden a unicycle for almost 50 years, started when I was in first grade.

Answer (score 1):

This is not meant to be a me too answer.

To do a just comparison we need to examine  the different vehicles at similar speeds and terrain. Terrain may be downhill, uphill or flat or uneven. We must also consider factors such as road surface, unevenness and the total motion of the system as it moves on differing surfaces.

There is a noticeable phenomenon I call wobulation that a climbing or descending uni rider exhibits.
Since the body of the uni rider is constantly striving to remain centered over the unicycle, and their is no "rudder" effect from a second wheel, much energy is expended to maintain ones line of travel.

The unicycle at a posited top travelling speed of lets say 15 mph (29 or 36 incher designed for distance travel) has a tendency to gyrate first to the right, then to the left of the line of forward motion. This constant crossing and correcting on the center line wastes considerable energy and the unicycle can be seen deviating side to side several cm with each wheel revolution. Check out videos of any of the many long distance uni riders on Youtube.

There is math to support what is observed. I am an electrical engineer and unicyclist and not prepared to exhibit a math proof as I just came across this FAQ. Any serious cyclist who has ever ridden for much distance with a uni rider knows that for the same amount of payload and same terrain the bicyclist does lots of waiting and holding back because the uni rider is severely limited by the system ridden.

The unicyclist's wheel path is a very obvious wavy line, Bicycles exhibit this wobble behavior also but not to nearly the same degree because of the stabilization of the second wheel Note: an experienced cyclist in a tucked position can hold a steady line with both wheels tracking straight at some speed.

Unicyclists use energy in two planes plus slight vertical deviation to make progress. Bicycles use much less energy in the second plane and vertically.

Slim Chestnut,
Engineer for over 55 years. Bicyclist and unicycist. Cycling Instructor and advocate for cycling. I have over 150,000 miles of cycling experience.

The unicycist "Boberto" is correct about the extra work unicyclsits do.

Comment: Although the side to side motion would be an energy loss, I don't think it's anywhere as significant as the points Bobberto had.  The complete lack of gearing and requirement that your feet _always_ move with the wheel motion is a huge energy sink when a regular cycle would be able to "coast".  This is especially important because people don't have much in the way of "energy recovery" when it comes to pedaling your legs.  It will put some strain on your muscles even if the pedals are actually pushing on your feet (going down a hill for example).

Answer (score -1):

Unicycle.  Less friction (no chain, no rear sprocket, no rear tire & less overall weight).

Answer (score -3):

I'd say a unicycle due to less friction. Though it would be harder to control.

My reasons as to why it'd have less friction are the same as @DIYser.

Comment: Care to put some 'flesh on these bones'? Physics SE is looking for answers that are less opinion based than this one.

Comment: Hi Laff. We expect answers here to give detailed explanations. Can you explain how to calculate the frictional losses of a bicycle and unicycle then show the losses in the unicycle are lower?

Comment: This is a "me too". You should vote to express that sentiment.